# JAXB not creating member variables and getters and setters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to generate Java classes form xsd schema and I am using JAXB. For the most part when I run the process to generate the classes it works. However there are a few classes that the member variable, getters , and setters are not generated. Here is what I have

File ns2.xsd

```
<xs:element name="Observation" type="ns2:ObservationType" substitutionGroup="ns1:_MetaData"/>
<xs:complexType name="ObservationType" mixed="true">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:extension base="ns1:AbstractType">
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns2:identifier"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

File ns3.xsd

```
<xs:element name="Observation" type="ns3:ObservationType" substitutionGroup="ns2:Observation"/>
<xs:complexType name="ObservationType" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>this extends the ns2:ObservationType </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:extension base="ns2:ObservationType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ns3:deliveryInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This creates an empty class

```
package mypackage.ns3;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * this extends the ns2:ObservationType 
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ObservationType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ObservationType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://earth.esa.int/ns2}ObservationType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://earth.esa.int/ns3}deliveryInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ObservationType")
public class ObservationType
    extends mypackage.ns2.ObservationType
{


}
```

My question is why is not creating the required member variable and its setters and getters?  Is there something wrong with the schema or is there a limitation on JAXB to create the missing information form complex types that use extensions from different files?
Thank you in advance. Your help or comments will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the classes? Command line tool, Ant, Maven,...? Can you provide us the exact configuration?

Comment: I am using the command line tool.                                                 "xjc  -d PATH_DESTINATION -b BINDING_FILE_LOCATION.xjb  ns3.xsd " I only use the binding file to specified the package name

Comment: If you thinkg you've found a bug, please file an issue here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

Answer (score 2):

What makes this use case odd is that you have inheritance in your XML Schema between two types with mixed content.  I think there is an XJC (and possibly spec) bug here, and as suggested by Puce you should enter a bug for it at the following link:

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

### XML Schema

**schema.xsd**

Here is a simpler XML schema that reproduces the same issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="b" mixed="true">
                 <sequence>
                   <element ref="tns:bb"/>
                </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <complexType name="c">
        <complexContent mixed="true">
            <extension base="tns:b">
                <sequence>
                   <element ref="tns:cc"/>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <element name="bb" type="string"/>

    <element name="cc" type="string"/>

</schema>
```

### Incorrect Java Model

**B**

The class generated for the `b` type is fine.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "b", propOrder = {"content"})
@XmlSeeAlso({C.class})
public class B {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "bb", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

**C**

The class generated for the `c` type is wrong, the question is what should it be?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "c")
public class C extends B {


}
```

### Better Java Model? - Option #1

You could add a property to the `C` class.  The question then comes down to which of the mixed text goes on the property inherited from `B` and which goes in the property defined on `C`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "c")
public class C
    extends B
{

    @XmlElementRef(name = "cc", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content2;

}
```

### Better Java Model? - Option #2

You could extend the property on `B` to be aware of the element reference from the `c` type.  This will allow you to handle the XML correctly for the `b` and `c` types but would allows some documents that weren't valid against the XML schema.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "b", propOrder = {"content"})
@XmlSeeAlso({C.class})
public class B {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "bb", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "cc", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am new at this. How do you specify that on the schema?. Thxs

Comment: is there a work around that can i can specify on a binding file?

Comment: @user2639371 - At the moment you won't be able to get a JAXB impl to generate either of these options.  You can code classes and have XJC point at them through a bindings file.  Do you prefer option #1 or 2?